# Having trouble searching through a list selenium

Tags: java, list, selenium

I am having a spot of difficulties searching through a list in selenium in Java.

I have a page which lists a bunch of news articles and I want to be able to search through this multi rowed and multi-columned table searching for specific strings.

I tried the following:

```
Dimension rowcount = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='z_c']/tbody/tr[*]/th/a[1]/strong")).getSize();
System.out.println(rowcount);
```

this prints out (80, 15) in the console.
I try this:

```
List<WebElement> txt = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.d_g.d_g1>tbody>tr"));
System.out.println(txt.size());
```

and this prints out the following in the console: 0

Im not sure if I am using cssSelector properly as my knowledge of the syntax and understanding is not good.

The html is as follows:

```
<table id="z_c" class="d_g d_gl" summary="List of news items">
<tbody>
<tr class="fgskip" style="visibility:hidden;">
<tr class="d_gactr">
<tr class="d_gh">
<tr>
<td class="d_gd_sel" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-left:0px;border-bottom:none;">
<th class="d_gdb d_ich" scope="row">
<a class="vui-link" href="/d2l/lms/news/newedit.d2l?ou=6606&newsId=998&Global=0" title="Edit US Elections">
<strong>**US Elections**</strong>
</a>
<a id="z_o" class="dcm dcm_handle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0" title="Actions for US Elections">
<span id="z_p" style="display:none;">
</th>
<td class="d_gn d_gc d_gdb" style="padding-right:0.9em;padding-left:0.9em;">
<td class="d_gn d_gc d_gdb" style="padding-right:0.9em;padding-left:0.9em;">
<td class="d_gn d_gc d_gdb" style="padding-right:0.9em;padding-left:0.9em;">
</tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<td class="d_gd" style="border-right:none"> </td>
<td class="d_gd" colspan="4">
<div id="z_q" class="drt" style="margin-top:0.9em;display: block;">
<p>**Elections will start on the 8 November**</p>
</div>
<div class="dco" style="margin-top:0.9em;margin-bottom:0.9em;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>

<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow">
<tr>
<tr class="d_detailsRow d_lastRow">
<tr class="d_gactr">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Im trying to search the table for the news headline:

****US Elections****

and the news content:

**Elections will start on the 8 November**

I can retrieve the data:

```
String getTableValue1 =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='z_c']/tbody/tr[4]/th/a[1]/strong")).getText();
String getTableValue2 =driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='z_c']/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")).getText();
System.out.println(getTableValue1);
System.out.println(getTableValue2);
```

But if someone can advise on how to search through this list to get the result it would be great.

Tarquin

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it sucks the data out of the table:

```
List<WebElement> txt = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.d_g.d_gl>tbody>tr"));
int total_nodes = txt.size();
for(int i =0 ; i< total_nodes; i++)
{
    String subject = txt.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(subject);
}
```

Im just trying to match the element to my search string now